# Understanding the mechanisms of IntentService?

Tags: android

I'm trying to understand the IntentService class so that I can build my own extension in which I can block the queue the handles all the threads whenever I want. The code below has been copied from here: http://www.google.com/codesearch#cZwlSNS7aEw/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/IntentService.java&q=IntentService&exact_package=android&type=cs

In my main Activity I have the following code:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,DownloadService.class);
            for(int i=0;i<filesArray.length;i++){
                 startService(intent);
             }
```

The code basically starts an IntentService for every file in the array. Now I want to know how does the IntentService class queue up this threads or services and in particular I want to know how I can modify the IntentService class to stop 'end' the service and clear the queue from all the threads which are waiting to be processed. Really appreciate any help o this. It has been bothering me for quite some time now!!!!

```
public abstract class IntentService extends Service {
    private volatile Looper mServiceLooper;
    private volatile ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;
    private String mName;
    private boolean mRedelivery;

    private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
        public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
            super(looper);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            onHandleIntent((Intent)msg.obj);
            stopSelf(msg.arg1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
     *
     * @param name Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
     */
    public IntentService(String name) {
        super();
        mName = name;
    }

    /**
     * Sets intent redelivery preferences.  Usually called from the constructor
     * with your preferred semantics.
     *
     * <p>If enabled is true,
     * {@link #onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)} will return
     * {@link Service#START_REDELIVER_INTENT}, so if this process dies before
     * {@link #onHandleIntent(Intent)} returns, the process will be restarted
     * and the intent redelivered.  If multiple Intents have been sent, only
     * the most recent one is guaranteed to be redelivered.
     *
     * <p>If enabled is false (the default),
     * {@link #onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)} will return
     * {@link Service#START_NOT_STICKY}, and if the process dies, the Intent
     * dies along with it.
     */
    public void setIntentRedelivery(boolean enabled) {
        mRedelivery = enabled;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO: It would be nice to have an option to hold a partial wakelock
        // during processing, and to have a static startService(Context, Intent)
        // method that would launch the service & hand off a wakelock.

        super.onCreate();
        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("IntentService[" + mName + "]");
        thread.start();

        mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
        mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
        msg.arg1 = startId;
        msg.obj = intent;
        mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        onStart(intent, startId);
        return mRedelivery ? START_REDELIVER_INTENT : START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mServiceLooper.quit();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * This method is invoked on the worker thread with a request to process.
     * Only one Intent is processed at a time, but the processing happens on a
     * worker thread that runs independently from other application logic.
     * So, if this code takes a long time, it will hold up other requests to
     * the same IntentService, but it will not hold up anything else.
     *
     * @param intent The value passed to {@link
     *               android.content.Context#startService(Intent)}.
     */
    protected abstract void onHandleIntent(Intent intent);
}
```

EDIT: 
I'm trying to Download multiples files one by one using an IntentService. However, when the Internet Connection is down the IntentService gets stuck on the current thread that it is processing or it just continues it's lifecycle. I want to end the service's lifecycle when the Internet connection is down.

EDIT:
I have copied the code for the IntentService and created a class MyIntentService using the same code.  I have made the following changes to the code:

```
    public volatile Looper mServiceLooper;
    public volatile ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;
    public String mName;
    public boolean mRedelivery;

    final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
        public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
            super(looper);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            onHandleIntent((Intent)msg.obj);
            stopSelf(msg.arg1);
        }
    }
```

the vars above have been made public and the inside class has been changed to final class. Now in my DownloadService which extends the MyIntentService I have a code like the following:

```
if(!isOnline()){
    mServiceHandler.removeMessages(0);
    mServiceLooper.quit();
    stopSelf();
}
```

I'm checking first if we have Internet connection, if not then I'm removing the messages from the service handler's queue (assuming i'm doing it correctly), I'm stoping the loop, and i'm stoping the service which i'm not sure which service it is stopping. HEELP!!

Comment: It's nice to find a copy of the source despite of codesearch.google.com being closed!

Comment: Yes please correct your broken link !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An intent service will hold a queue of intents that are automatically run on a separate thread. The service lives for as long as there are messages to be processed. The messages are guaranteed to be run sequentially.

You have no control over when the service finishes it's lifecycle but that shouldn't matter to you. It is all transparent from your point of view.

EDIT: you will need to handle the queue manually and expose a method to clear it when needed.

I believe the Handler.removeMessages method will do the trick.

Also take a look at this: [Drop intents while IntentService is processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089785/drop-intents-while-intentservice-is-processing)

EDIT:

I have never done this myself and can't be sure if it will work. What you want is to set the "what" of the message before it is send so you can remove it after. In the onStart method a Message is obtained and two parameters are set. Also try setting the 'what' parameter.

Comment: "You have no control over when the service finishes it's lifecycle but that shouldn't matter to you" that is the precise reason, why I posted this question! It matters to me and I want to extend IntentService so that I have more control over the queue processing the intents.

Comment: I'm trying to Download multiples files one by one using an IntentService. However, when the Internet Connection is down the IntentService gets stuck on the current thread that it is processing or it just continues it's lifecycle. I want to end the service's lifecycle when the Internet connection is down.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reponse. The removeMessages(int what) takes a parameter... what should I pass as the parameter !!

Comment: I added some more information to my question on how i did but it doesn't work!!! Help!!

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, I eventually implemented my own IntentService. You can have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004235/implementation-of-intentservice-using-linkedblockingqueue

Answer (score 0):

The reason removeMessages wasn't working for you is because the `what` field of the `Message` is never set, you need to set that and then clear accordingly.